# Iterate over a list and return the maximum sum of n continuous values

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

**Problem Definition:**
There are N boxes containing either a prize or a penalty. A positive value 
indicates that it is a prize and a negative value indicates that it is a
 penalty. The N values indicating the prize amount or penalty amount is 
passed as the input to the program. A man can pick any number of boxes 
but those boxes must be arranged continuously. The program must print the
 maximum prize money that can be selected by the man.

**Boundary condition(s):**

1<=n<=10^5

**Input Format:**

The first line contains N.

The second line contains the N integers representing the prize or penalty amount separated by a space.

**Example Input/Output 1:**
Input:
9
2 -4 4 3 -2 -1 7 -4 3

Output:
11

Explanation:
The maximum prize amount can be obtained when the man picks the following five boxes 4 3 -2 -1 7

**Example Input/Output 2:**
Input :
20
63 78 111 43 104 -89 35 57 -55 84 111 91 -18 50 42 100 -67 84 70 63

Output:

957

**Example Input/Output 3:**
Input :
5
-5 -6 -8 -7 -9

Output :
0


**Max Execution Time Limit:** 200 millisecs

I can solve this problem and my algorithm is correct but the execution time exceeds the time limit.

```
a=int(input())
b=list(map(int,input().split()))
e=[]
for i in range(2,a+1):
    if i!=a:
        for j in range(a-i+1):
            s=0
            for k in range(j,i+j):
                s+=b[k]
            e.append(s)
    else:
        s=0
        for k in range(a):
            s+=b[k]
        e.append(s)
print(max(e))
```

Comment: Possibly https://codereview.stackexchange.com would be more helpful

Comment: Try to use DP (dynamic programming) approach, it will solve your problem in linear time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is an example of [maximum subarray sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) and you could solve this with O(n) time complexity with [kadane's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm) algorithm(which is greedy in nature).

**Snippet:**

```
a=int(input())
b=list(map(int,input().split()))

maximum = b[0]
sum = b[0]
for i in range(1,a):
    if sum < 0:
        sum = 0
    sum += b[i]
    maximum = max(maximum,sum)
print(maximum)
```

**Algorithm:**

- We keep 2 variables, current `sum` and `maximum` which holds the answer.
- We keep adding array values to `sum`. If the current `sum` is less than `0`, then we make the current `sum` equal to `0` and then add further elements. We do this because we want to keep `sum` as maximum(and possibly positive) as possible.
- In the end, we keep updating `maximum` value with it and print the `maximum`.

**Update:**

Since this problem deals with collecting prize money, collecting negative amount doesn't make sense. So, the **only** change is to initialize maximum to `0` at first and start the loop from `0`.

**Snippet:**

```
a=int(input())
b=list(map(int,input().split()))

maximum = 0
sum = 0
for i in range(0,a):
    if sum < 0:
        sum = 0
    sum += b[i]
    maximum = max(maximum,sum)
print(maximum)
```

Answer (score 1):

@vivek_23 solution is faster, but I'll give my approach too. This will reduce iterations:

```
a=int(input())
b=list(map(int,input().split()))
print(max(sum(b[start:end]) for start in range(a) for end in range(0, a + 1) if start < end))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are doing to many iterations of the length of the list. Instead you need to think of a better approach. One possible solution could be a recursive one where you check from 1 to length of inputs finding the biggest total then recursively call your function passing the remaining inputs excluding the first. this will then perform the same check again until there are no more inputs left to check.

This isnt as fast as @vivek_23's answer but will give you another insight to approach to such a problem.

```py
def max_value(input_list, maximum=float('-inf')):
    input_len = len(input_list)
    if input_len:
        for i in range(1, input_len + 1):
            this_total = sum(input_list[:i])
            if this_total > maximum:
                maximum = this_total
        return max_value(input_list[1:], maximum)
    else:
        return maximum if maximum > 0 else 0


test_inputs = [
    '2 -4 4 3 -2 -1 7 -4 3',
    '63 78 111 43 104 -89 35 57 -55 84 111 91 -18 50 42 100 -67 84 70 63',
    '-5 -6 -8 -7 -9'
]

from timeit import default_timer as timer
for test_input in test_inputs:
    start = timer()
    print(max_value([int(num) for num in test_input.split()]))
    end = timer()
    print('func time taken', end - start)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
11
func time taken 0.0009307380000000143
957
func time taken 0.0003775810000000157
0
func time taken 4.153400000000973e-05
```